# Is it possible to change travel date after I receive UK visa?

Tags: visas, uk, applications

I have applied for Tier 2 long term visa and it is in process but I want to change my travel date.

I submitted my visa application on 27 Jan and planned start date is 1 March but I want to travel by 1 April.

Can someone please let me know the process to apply for a travel date replacement?